# Unable to Post with Ajax.BeginForm from View to Controller in MVC 3 using PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, pagedlist, ajax.beginform

I'm having trouble posting values using Ajax.BeginForm from the view to the controller in my application using the Pagelist.Mvc package in NuGet. Here is a sample of my code for a delete action:

Model:

```
namespace test1.Models
{
    public class UploadItem
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Directory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<UploadItem>
@using test1.Models;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@foreach (UploadItem item in Model)
{
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteItem", "Upload", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"}))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.FileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Directory)

        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test1.Models;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using PagedList;

namespace test1.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteItem(IPagedList<UploadItem> uploadItems)
        {
            UploadHelper.DeleteFileFromDirectory(uploadItems[0].FileName,
            uploadItems[0].Directory);

            var listOfUploadedFiles = UploadHelper.GenerateListOfUploads();
            const int rows = 5;
            const int page = 1;
            int index = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
            var uploadedFiles = listOfUploadedFiles.ToPagedList(index, rows);
            ViewBag.UploadedItems = uploadedFiles;
            ViewBag.PageNum = page;
            return View(uploadedFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to avoid using Javascript directly at the moment to perform the post.

Comment: is there any error you are getting? put a break point and see what error you get.

Comment: No Error, The hidden values aren't posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by referencing a partial view (_UploadSingleItem):

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<UploadItem>
@using test1.Models;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@foreach (UploadItem item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_UploadSingleItem", item)
}
```

_UploadSingleItem View:

```
@model UploadItem
@using test1.Models;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteItem", "Upload", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.FileName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Directory)

    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

Then changing the controller to accept a List instead of an IPagedList:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test1.Models;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using PagedList;

namespace test1.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteItem(List<UploadItem> uploadItems)
        {
            UploadHelper.DeleteFileFromDirectory(uploadItems[0].FileName,
            uploadItems[0].Directory);

            var listOfUploadedFiles = UploadHelper.GenerateListOfUploads();
            const int rows = 5;
            const int page = 1;
            int index = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
            var uploadedFiles = listOfUploadedFiles.ToPagedList(index, rows);
            ViewBag.UploadedItems = uploadedFiles;
            ViewBag.PageNum = page;
            return View(uploadedFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to post values :)

It seems MVC has problems binding correctly to the model when the Ajax.Beginform is directly within a loop.